# When to use REST API, when to use Messaging Service (e.g RabbitMQ) in exchanging data between Microservices?

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices

I am building a system using microservices architecture, using RabbitMQ as the messaging service.
I have a use cases of communication between 2 services and face the difficulties of using RabbitMQ to implement it.

Cart-Service needs to get data from Product-Service. In this case Cart-Service can send a message, Product-Service subscribes to that message. But I find no way for Product-Service to send back the data to Cart-Service.

May you let me know whether my approach of using RabbitMQ in this case is correct?
Any other approach I should apply in this use case?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use an event-driven naming convention for your rabbitMQ message routes. The format can be `<service>.<entity>.<action>`, e.g. "cart.item.added".

Cart service subscribes to `product.*.*` messages, Product service - to the `cart.*.*` ones.

The workflow might be the following:

- cart: publishes "cart.item.added" message.
- product: receives "cart.item.added" message, publishes "product.product.read" one
- cart: receives "product.product.read" message with the product info.

If you're using Node.js for the microservices, you could read more on how to prototype RabbitMQ message exchange here:

https://medium.com/@krawa76/bootstrap-node-js-microservice-stack-4a348db38e51

Comment: May I know whether it is better to use HTTP protocol which is synchronous in this use case?
I'm thinking about later when we have multiple container for cart services, then the instance that receives "product.product.read" is not the correct one.
E.g Instance 1 of cart services publishes, but instance 2 of cart services receives the message from product service.

Comment: RESTful API should work well for this case of 1-to-1 microservices communication. On the other hand, if you need to connect more services that react to the product-related events (say, a notification service), you'll need to add more logic to one of the existing ones vs adding an extra subscriber service. Anyway, if it's a definite synchronous one-to-one request/response - then use API, otherwise use a message broker.